# Concatenate a slice of `&str`s into an owned `String`

Tags: string, vector, rust, iterator, type-conversion

I am trying to concatenate every element in a slice of `&str`s (`&[&str]`) into a single owned `String`. For example, I want to turn `&['Hello', ' world!']` into `"Hello world!"`.

I tried to do this by converting the slice into an iterator, then mapping over the iterator and converting each `&str` into an owned `String`, then collect them all into a `Vec<String>` and running `.join("")`, but I keep getting a type error.

Here is my code:

```rust
fn concat_str(a: &[&str]) -> String {
    a.into_iter().map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect::<Vec<String>>().join("")
}

fn main() {
    let arr = ["Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Lion"];

    println!("{}", concat_str(&arr[..3])); // should print "DogCatBird"
    println!("{}", concat_str(&arr[2..])); // should print "BirdLion"
    println!("{}", concat_str(&arr[1..3])); // should print "CatBird"
}
```

And here is the compiler error that I am getting:

```rust
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<String>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&str`
    --> code.rs:2:38
     |
2    |     a.into_iter().map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect::<Vec<String>>().join("")
     |                                         ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>`
     |
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<&str>` is not implemented for `Vec<String>`
note: required by a bound in `collect`
    --> /Users/michaelfm1211/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:1780:19
     |
1780 |     fn collect<B: FromIterator<Self::Item>>(self) -> B
     |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `collect`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

It says that I cannot collect into a `Vec<String>` because the iterator is not of a `String`, but I thought that I had converted it to a `String` with `.map(|s| s.to_owned())`.

How can I fix this? I am also new to rust, so it would be very helpful is someone could explain what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`into_iter` will yield an iterator with `Item=&&str`. In your map, `.to_owned()` converts that into a `&str`, which doesn't work. There are a few ways to fix that, you could use `.copied` or `.cloned` to get a `&str`:

```rust
a.into_iter().copied().map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect::<Vec<String>>().join("")
// or
a.into_iter().cloned().map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect::<Vec<String>>().join("")
```

Or you could use `.to_string()` to get a `String` directly:

```rust
a.into_iter().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect::<Vec<String>>().join("")
```

Note, you can also just `collect` into a `String` when you don't want a separator directly:

```rust
a.into_iter().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect::<String>()
```

Comment: `.join("")` -> `.concat()`.

Answer (score 2):

There are the methods [`join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join) and [`concat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.concat) on slice directly, so you can write:

```rust
fn concat_str(a: &[&str]) -> String {
    a.concat()
}
```

which gives you the desired output

Answer (score 0):

```rust
fn concat_str(a: &[&str]) -> String {
    a.iter()
     .cloned()
     .collect()
}
```